# Unable to git push by gitignore

Tags: git, github

I have git folder with hirarchy as follow:

I have a folder jobs.

Jobs folder have subfolders myjob1/, myjob2/
and Each subfolder's have folder build/

Here I wanted to ignore only the `jobs/**/build` folder and push remaining data to git

```
$ls
 jobs/
 .gitignore
$cat .gitignore
 jobs/**/build
$ls jobs/
 myjob1/
 myjob2/
$ls jobs/myjob1/
 config.xml
 build
$ls jobs/myjob2/
 config.xml
 build
$ cat .gitignore
  jobs/**/build
$git add jobs
$git commit -m "jobs added"
 On branch master
 Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
 nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Can anyone helpme in pushing this data?

Comment: Unrelated: try using ```git status``` for checking your files instead of committing them. Will give you a clearer overview.

Comment: You haven’t changed anything and you’re not pushing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain why your current solution isn't working is because.

What you want is specifically targeting the `build/` folders. I think this can be done using a wildcard before `/build/`. Either like this:

```
**/build/
```

Or this way if you specifically want `build` folders inside the `jobs` directory:

```
jobs/*/build/
jobs/**/build/
```

I have tried all these options locally and they worked for me.

Comment: I tried with `**/build/` , `jobs/*/build/` and `/jobs/*/build/`. Still facing same issue

Comment: no i have not commited them before. Did you tried this?

Comment: Locally I managed to do it with ```**/build```. ```**/build/```, ```jobs/*/build/``` and ```jobs/**/build/``` also work.

Comment: Amazing :) Don't forget to accept if you think the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you previously pushed that files, for git to ignore them now you have to reverse the previous commit reseting HEAD and the you will be able to ignore them.

## EDIT

I think because jobs folder apparently is in the root of your repo. it should be `/jobs/**/build`. I have recreated a similar situation and in this ways it works.

Comment: That is not what op is asking.

Comment: I have pushed the .ignore first then added jobs folder and trying to git push

Comment: I think it should be /jobs/**/build

Comment: getting still same error after changed to `/jobs/**/build`

Comment: I modified the .gitignore. Pushed the chages. Added jobs folder. then `git add jobs` now `git commit -m "adding jobs" ` giving me error "nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Comment: Maybe if you do `git add .` instead, then try to commit.

Comment: I don't think specifying that ```jobs``` is a root folder makes a ton of difference in this case.